# hide or show content with CanCan based on role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

I need to hide some form fields in a form when a user is not a certain role. How could that be done? From the docs I know you can give access to certain actions like show, update or just manage

But how to do something like  if user.role? :admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  if cannot? :manage ,Articles
  flash[:notice] = "you are not authorized to manage articles"

  end
```

Comment: Problem Is I have a profiles controller and only want to limit access to a portion of the form fields, so a full user would get more form fields ( its for a search form ) I don't see how i could do that with CanCan in this setup

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to do it through cancan it will all depend on how you have your abilities setup. With that in mind, if the user has full privileges you can just use:

```
<% if can? :manage, :all %>
  <%= f.text_field :field_name %>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise you can be more specific and specify a base model/action that a user needs to have privileges to like so:

```
<% if can? :update, Profile %>
  <%= f.text_field :field_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is mostly copied from the [CanCan documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/#readme).

First, you define an [Ability class](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities).  You can generate one of these using:

```
rails g cancan:ability
```

This should give you something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

In this class you can define whatever abilities you want the user to have.  In the above example, an admin can manage any object.  A user who is not an admin or who is not logged in can read any object.

After you've defined your abilities, you need to [check your abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/checking-abilities) using the `can?` method.  In your view you could write something like:

```
<% if can? :create, Project %>
  <!-- your form view logic goes here -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: That throws an undefined method `role?' I call this from inside a profiles controller partial ( not collection partial ) strangely it gives undefined method. role is in attribute accessible and the role system works fine on all other places, just i cannot get this if statement to work

Comment: I guess he meant you should put a role? method on your user model and simply check that like you would normally without cancan

Comment: My answer was supposed to be called in the view where you are displaying your form.  I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Ok Ive looked a bit into this and the answer to solve this issue is how to get the role of current_user.id ( devise ) so I could just check if a certain user == admin or == default if the role of current_user.id == admin then i would display the extra form fields, else not. Any idea on how to get the role of current user?

Comment: You're going to have to post some code.  I don't really know why my answer wouldn't have worked.  I need to see what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<% if user.admin? %>
  <!-- form field -->
<% elsif user.editor? %>
  <!-- another form field -->
<% end %>
```